# Proving or disproving that if $ A^2 X = \lambda^2 X $ then $AX = \lambda X $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Recently found out I don't know how to prove or disprove this proposition for any $A \in \mathbb{K}^{3 \times 3}$.

Proving that the later implies the first  one is straightforward, but with this problem I can only find a way to prove it with $A$ being invertible, which is not part of the hypothesis, and as far as I know it is not enough to prove that $A$ *needs* to be invertible for the proposition to be true.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is a non-zero matrix with $A^2=0$.

Comment: You can't even prove it when $A$ is invertible, so whatever you did there must have a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Arthur wouldn't left-multiplying both terms with the inverse leave us with $ AX=\lambda X$  ?

Comment: No, it would leave us with $AX=\lambda^2A^{-1}X$, with nowhere to really go from there.

Comment: Oh you are right, thanks for the help

Comment: Let $A=-I$, $\lambda = 1$. Then $A^2 x = \lambda^2 x$ but $Ax \neq \lambda x$ unless $x=0$.

Comment: in general you want to focus on *involutions* here... especially consider any $A\not\propto I$ but $A^2=I$ so any non-zero $x$  is an eigenvector of $A^2$ but this won't be the case for $A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ and $\lambda$ are such that both of these hold:
$$A^2 X = \lambda^2 X\\
AX = \lambda X.$$  But then we immediately find  an example where the implication fails, since if $$\mu=-\lambda$$ then $$A^2 X =\mu^2 X$$ but $$AX\ne \mu X.$$   So the implication cannot hold for all $A$ and all $\lambda$.

It's possible that one could prove that if $A^2X=\lambda^2 X$ then $AX=\pm\lambda X$, but I don't know.

Comment: Like this proof a lot, very straightforward

Comment: Thanks, it's because I'm not very smart!

Comment: Of course, you are implicitly assuming $\lambda X \ne \mu X$, i.e., that $\lambda \ne 0$, $X \ne 0$, and, as is probably implicit, $\mathbb K$ does not have characteristic $2$.  (This is my second try at being a smart alec.  The first time, I forgot that $\lambda$ could also be $0$.)

Comment: Yes, I considered mentioning that and decided to leave it out.

Answer (score 7):

$$0=\operatorname{det}(A^2-\lambda^2 I)=\operatorname{det}\left(A-\lambda I)\cdot (A+\lambda I)\right)=\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I)\cdot \operatorname{det}(A+\lambda I),$$ so $\lambda$ or $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ (maybe both or maybe only $-\lambda$), so the statement is not true. Take for example $-I$, whose unique eigenvalue is $-1$ with multiplicity $3$. $(-I)^2=I$ have $1$ as eigenvalue but $-I$ not.

Comment: I don't understand you. What do you mean?

Comment: Before your edit, you hadn't really fully answered the problem statement. You had shown that $AX=kX$ means $k=\pm\lambda$, but you hadn't shown that $k=-\lambda$ was possible. With an example, that's all fixed.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for your observation! :)